# Regular expression with beginning of line

Tags: regex, go

I'd like to use a regular expression which matches the beginning of a line in a text. For some reason, `^` does not work, see this failing test:

```
func TestNewLine(t *testing.T) {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("^bar")
    match := re.FindString("foo\nbar\nbaz")
    assert.Equal(t, "bar", match)
}
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Or use a multi-line match with `m`

Comment: @Flimzy - I'd like my ultimate regex to span over many lines, so splitting is not quite suitable for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to enable multi line mode flag for regex evaluation. Try this:

```
func TestNewLine(t *testing.T) {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?m)^(bar)")
    match := re.FindString("foo\nbar\nbaz")
    assert.Equal(t, "bar", match)
}
```

Comment: Note [`regexp/syntax`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax) documents the supported syntax and says of the `m` flag: "multi-line mode: ^ and $ match begin/end line in addition to begin/end text (default false)"